# How do we know that a potential korban is not אֶתְנַן זוֹנָה וּמְחִיר כֶּלֶב?

Tags: halacha, korban, arayot, ki-teitzei

אֶתְנַן זוֹנָה וּמְחִיר כֶּלֶב 
are invalid for an offering. [Devorim 23:19](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9987#showrashi=true).

For example, as Rashi explains, “If one exchanged a dog for a lamb [this lamb is unfit for a sacrifice].”

How does the person taking the animal to shecht it for the altar know that it is not an  אֶתְנַן זוֹנָה וּמְחִיר כֶּלֶב?

Do we follow the majority and assume that unless he knows otherwise the animal is suitable for an offering or are there more stringent rules for sacrifices?

How do we know that a potential korban is not  אֶתְנַן זוֹנָה וּמְחִיר כֶּלֶב?

Comment: You mean a case where he is buying it from someone else? If it is his then what's the problem?

Comment: @DoubleAA I wasn't sure if perhaps he meant the Kohen.

Comment: @YEZ Perhaps, though even a Zar can Shecht. (The OP is a Kohein fwiw)

Comment: perhaps relevant http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?mfid=86124&rid=8139

Comment: I did mean the kohen or the zar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a classic *ruba d'leisa kaman*. In the overall population, a very, very small number of animals are prohibited. Knowing nothing else, presented with an animal before us, we assume it is permitted.

(This is known as "leisa kaman", "it does not appear before us", as the negative outcome is a theoretical. A weaker form of *rov* is "ruba d'isa kaman", "a majority appearing before us", e.g. we know that there is one non-kosher item mixed in with these ten kosher ones, but we don't know which is which.)

The Gemara in Chulin uses the concept of *ruba d'leisa kaman* with regards to checking for *treifos.* An animal with a brain aneurysm is going to die soon and is a *treifa*, therefore not fit as a sacrifice; however for a *korban olah* we burn the brain whole, rather than dissect it. Isn't there a small chance this animal is invalidated? We don't concern ourselves with that chance.

If we need not concern ourselves with the miniscule theoretical probability that this cow has a brain tumor, then we also wouldn't concern ourselves with the miniscule theoretical probability that it was used as a harlot's wage or as barter for a dog. (Unless you're living in a time or place where that's incredibly super-duper common.)

Comment: @YEZ 11 +/- 2 .

Comment: Yes. Is the din the same whether it is a physical blemish of which you speak or the rather different sort of problem of harlot's wage or barter for a dog?

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok why should it be any different? We don't concern ourselves with theoretical rare events.

Comment: @Shalom My concern was that the אֶתְנַן זוֹנָה וּמְחִיר כֶּלֶב was more abhorrent than a physical defect. If so I would expect  אֶתְנַן כֶּלֶב וּמְחִיר זוֹנָה to be equally bad. But [it isn't](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/8404n.htm) halacha 17. So I am finally convinced. Thanks.